# Way to order object properties in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an Object called onlineInClubsCount

```
{
    name: 12,
    anotherName: 2,
    anotherOne: 74
}
```

which i iterate through ng-repeat like:

```
<a ng-repeat="(club,value) in onlineInClubsCount" class="item item-avatar" ng-href="#/app/clubs/{{club}}">
    <img ng-src="img/tc-logo.jpeg">
    <h2>{{club}}</h2>
    <p>Peoples inside: {{value}}</p>
</a>
```

My problem is that i don't get, how to sort my object properties by their value. I know that there is default filter orderBy in Angular, but i don't get how to use it in my situation

Comment: What does ng-repeat="(club,value) in onlineInClubsCount | orderBy:'value'" do?

Comment: *"sort my object by value"* ... objects are not sortable nor do they have order. Use arrays if you want sorting

Comment: do absolutely nothing (. Tried that before asking here

Comment: for now i solved my issue this way:
`for (var k in data){
                    $scope.onlineInClubsCountSortable.push({name: k, peopleInside: data[k]})
                }`

Answer (score 3):

Change your data to an array of objects

```
[
  { name: 'name 1', count:12},
  { name: 'name 2', count:66},
  { name: 'name 3', count:66}
]
```

Then you can use orderBy on an array

```
<a ng-repeat="club in onlineInClubsCount| orderBy:'count'">
  {{club.name}}
```

Comment: yup. Made that way. I just thought, there is easier way :D

Thanks

Comment: you can create a filter to return object as array also

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the documentation you could convert your object into an array that is sorted using this filter:  [toArrayFilter](https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular-toArrayFilter)

`angular.module('app', ['angular-toArrayFilter'])`

```
  <div ng:repeat="item in onlineInClubsCount | toArray | orderBy: '$value'" class="item item-avatar" ng-href="#/app/clubs/{{item.$key}}">
    <img ng-src="img/tc-logo.jpeg">
    <h2>{{item.$key}}</h2>
    <p>People inside: {{item.$value}}</p>
  </div>


$scope.onlineInClubsCount = {
    name: 12,
    anotherName:2,
    theOther:74
};
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but your solution looks more complicated for me, because i get my object via API, so less movements - better. But, anyway, thanks for idea)

Comment: I looked at ToArray filter and saw that you can keep your data object intact, check the edited version.